# Can a mapping have defaulted value

Tags: solidity

An example of a a mapping

```
mapping (address => address) yourNewMapping;
```

Is there a way to have

```
yourNewMapping[msg.sender] = defaultValue
```

Say upon default through a constructor, for all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it’s not possible to define a default value in that way.

A `mapping(KeyType => ValueType)` always maps a key onto a 256-bit/32-byte storage slot; if that storage slot is blank (e.g. it was never written to), [it will contain](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#mapping-types) `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. How these zero bytes are interpreted as a value [depends](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#default-value) on the `mapping`’s value-type. E.g. for a `mapping(? => bool)`, this 0-value will be parsed as `false`. For a `mapping` with value-type `address`, the 0-value will be parsed as `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, or `address(0)`.

So the default value for `mapping(address => address)` will be `address(0)`.

Assuming you will never be using 0 as an actual valid value, if you want to have a default value that is not 0, what you can do is to translate the 0-value to your desired default value every time you read the mapping, e.g.:

```
address value = yourNewMapping[msg.sender];
value = value == address(0) ? yourDefaultValue : value;
```

Comment: Just to clearify; default value of mapping is the default value of the second argument of map. So it's  0 for something mapped to a  x-> uint; `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` for x-> address and so on

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh I inserted a paragraph to elaborate on your clarification. Thanks.